# HTML input, blinking caret without focus?

Tags: css, html, forms, input

Is it possible to have the blinking caret appear permanataly in an HTML input without having to focus the input?

If not I will style a CSS div shaped like a caret to blink on and off and dissapear when focused, but before I go to that hassle is there an easier way?

Comment: Why? This sounds like a UX nightmare.

Comment: By "blinking caret" do you mean a blinking cursor? A caret is the little "up" shape.

Comment: @MichaelCoker A caret in this context can take lots of different shapes but most often today, it tends to be a flashing pipe-looking character. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_navigation

Comment: @Collin Ah, thanks! Yeah you can't fake a caret blinking outside of building your own, and totally sounds like a UX nightmare.

Comment: I love how you assume this will be a UX nightmare when you have no idea what I intend to actually use it for.

The answer I selected below is perfect for what I was trying to achieve :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give a try to animated background :

```css
input:focus {
  background-image:none;
}
input {
  animation: blink-empty 1s infinite;
  background-image:/*linear-gradient(black,black)*/ linear-gradient(red,red);
  background-position: 1px  center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:1px 1.2em;
}
@keyframes blink-empty {
  30%, 75%{background-size:1px 1.2em;}
  50% {background-size: 0 1.2em;}
}
```

```html
<p>fake carret on left side colored red for demo. but will not follow text if any.</p>
<input type="text" value=""/>
```

you can play with it at http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/jyLMLd

Comment: But when we type something and blur event triggers for input. cursor still blinks at the left position. Is it possible to move the cursor as well. any decent solution using jquery? 
PS:After hours of searching, I didn't find anything on internet :/

Comment: @AnkushMalik as states the answer, this fake cblinking cursor do not follow the text. it is drawn in the background. you can hide it on : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/YzzWZJy . you may look/search at textarea and carret and restyle it to an input size or even a contenteditable element . js or jquery should go along with your search result ;) **best would be to create a question with what you tried**