# Blinking text cursor without focus in the HTML-text input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a HTML-text field with some input. The focus of the input is lost since I searched in another component. From the search results I need to insert some text where the cursor/caret is located.

Since the focus is lost the cursor won't blink anymore. But than it gets hard to know the insert position for the user. Is there a chance to have a blinking caret/cursor without having the focus?

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41840340/325868) has the problem that it won't blink on the position the caret is currently located. If there is another UX-pattern for letting the user know where the text will be inserted I would welcome this idea as well.

Remark: The framework I'm coding with is Angular. Therefore JS, Typescript or Angular code is possible.

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question itself.

Comment: Since you cannot use any HTML inside an HTML `input`, I'm afraid any sustainable solution will have to involve replacing the `input` with your very own component. Anything else would just be a very hacky and unstable solution based on calculating characters widths and placing an absolute-positioned element that looks like a cursor at the position you need.

Comment: @Teemu: What kind of relevant code are you looking for? something like `<input>` or `<textarea>`?

Comment: Something you already have, thought it doesn't even work as you wish. If somebody's going to compose a code without a base, usually "no, I can't use this or that" comments appear.

Comment: Yeah, but the thing is you have an `<input>` element and than I should copy'n-paste the mentioned solution? Matter of fact if think little bit about the details what I'm asking about than it remains hard to say 'How to solve it?' (if not unpossbible)